# Using custom PHP file extensions with remote Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, file-extension

I am using .inc as a file extension throughout my PHP application to represent included classes. When using Xdebug with a debugging client (ie. PHPStorm), I am unable to debug set breakpoints on these individual files. The client only appears to observe breakpoints on .php files. I've tested another client called MacDBGp and am experiencing the same problems.

Is there a way to configure Xdebug to support other file types than the standard .php extension? Or is this a limitation by the DBGp protocol?

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose to use .inc and not .inc.php? I assume you dug through the documentation already and found that there is no way to configure this option. Maybe make a feature request on the bug tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Using .inc is insecure. Rename your files at minimum to .inc.php

Here's a quick way to recursively rename your files:

```
find /path/to/www -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)\.inc/mv \1.inc \1.inc.php/' | sh
```

Comment: Why is it stupid and insecure? There is no reasoning behind your argument.

Comment: Because if you deploy your code to standard server or your configs get reset during an update your source code is immediately exposed. In some shared environments it simply wont work. Not only that, anyone unfamiliar with the project would need to open the file to figure out what's in there.